# Rebus Stand and I

Tags: rebus

[image]

Yes, this is incredibly easy, but it's my first rebus.  I thought it was my own idea, but if someone did this before, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> I don't understand. ( "I" under "stand" that has been cut out)